# I send post request with fetch method in React but can not get cookies set by server

Tags: reactjs, cookies, fetch-api

My springboot app is running on cloud server and I use fetch() to send post request to it in my react app which is running on localhost:3000.

In my springboot app, I use setCookie method to set cookie in response. However, when I check the response sent back, there is no cookie, only to find Set-cookie:token=xxxxx in the response. I am so confused why it won’t set cookie instead of being here? I think it should be find in cookie but not this field.

It has something to do with CORS, since the request is from localhost:3000 which is different from the target url.

By the way, I don’t do anything special when using fetch method.

Also, I added @CrossOrigin to the Controller in springboot app. It works fine, the only thing is the cookie can not be set when sending request with fetch method

Comment: Have you tried to add "credentials: true" in your fetch request options?

Comment: Yes, it gives an error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to read the 'credentials' property from 'RequestInit': The provided value 'true' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials.

Comment: This is what I put in fetch(): fetch(baseUrl+api, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        credentials: true,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),}
    )

Comment: credentials inside quotes like "credentials" : true

Comment: I tried for both, 'true' and true but still not work:(